# How can I press Enter while writing in a Text Box?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In my C# project I have a text box and a button. What I want is:

1) the user writes something in the text box

2) clicks the "Enter" button

3) this automatically triggers the button1_Click event

Step 1 is straightforward.

For step 2 the problem is that after I write sth in the text box, it is still selected and I am forced to write "Enter" (new line) in the text box which doesn't happen and I hear an error sound.

For step 3 I used

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

But the code doesn't detect that the Enter key is presses and the code isn't ran at all. Any ideas how to fix this? I suppose I have to unselect the text box and then press Enter but I don't know how it works.

Comment: Subscribe to the KeyDown event of your TextBox instead of the Form's. Use `e.SuppresKeyPress = true` when `e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter`. Move the code you have in `button1.Click` to a method, so you can call it from where you need it, instead of performing clicks.